# Docusign - Send email after sign

Tags: docusignapi

I want to know if there is a way using the DocuSign API for send a copy of the document by email to other person that is not the one how sign the doc.

Actually we are going for the Embedding solution. So I'm sending the ClientUserId to avoid send the email. But I will need to send the sign doc after to another person.

Is there a way to do that from the API?

Thanks.

Update:

Im sending this Json: (Using compositeTemplates)

```
    {
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "carbonCopies": [{
                    "email": "mauriciotaranto@test.com",
                    "name": "CC Name",
                    "recipientId": "3",
                     "emailNotification": {
                        "emailBody":"email text",
                        "emailSubject":"Completed!!!! this is custom",
                        "supportedLanguage":"en"
                     },
                }],
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "mauriciotaranto@test.com",
                    "name": "A Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Participant A"
                }],
                 "Tabs":{
            "TextTabs":[
               {
                  "TabLabel":"PreferredPhoneNumber",
                  "Value":"001234567"
               },
                {
                  "TabLabel":"AlternatePhoneNumber",
                  "Value":"001234567"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"BirthMM",
                  "Value":"04"
               },
                {
                  "TabLabel":"BirrthDD",
                  "Value":"18"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"BirrthYY",
                  "Value":"1981"
               },
                {
                  "TabLabel":"DentalSchool",
                  "Value":"DentalSchool"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"MedicalSchool",
                  "Value":"MedicalSchool"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"OmsResidency",
                  "Value":"OmsResidency"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"Intership",
                  "Value":"Intership"
               },
                 {
                  "TabLabel":"Fellowship",
                  "Value":"Fellowship"
               },
                {
                  "TabLabel":" {",
                  "Value":"TrainingArea"
               },

            ],
            "RadioGroupTabs": [{
                "groupName": "RadioPhone",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": true,
                    "value": "Radio2"
                }],

            },
            {
                "groupName": "AlternatePhoneNumber",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": true,
                    "value": "Radio1"
                }],

            },
            {
                "groupName": "MemberShip",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": true,
                    "value": "Radio2"
                }],

            },
            {
                "groupName": "RiskManagement",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": true,
                    "value": "Radio2"
                }],

            }],
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "TabLabel": "SuffixDDS",
                "selected": true,
            },
            {
                "TabLabel": "SuffixMD",
                "selected": true,
            },
            ],
         },
            },

            "sequence": "2"
        }],
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4ca"
        }]
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Test flow with CC",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

The problem is that now when I get the email to sign the document I don't see any fields. And allow the user to drag and drop the fields. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the email after the sign of the document.

Thanks.

Comment: You have `tabs` outside the `signers`, instead it should be inside the `signers` tabs, also I saw you have a TextTab with `{`, is it correct? I have updated my answer with the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add that user as a `CC recipient` in the routing order, if this user needs to get an email after all the signers have completed the signing on the document then add this `CC recipient` at the last in the routing order.

[DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/carbonCopy) has details how to add CC recipient in an envelope using API. Sample JSON:

```
    {
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "carbonCopies": [{
                    "email": "mauriciotaranto@test.com",
                    "name": "CC Name",
                    "recipientId": "3",
                    "emailNotification": {
                        "emailBody": "email text",
                        "emailSubject": "Completed!!!! this is custom",
                        "supportedLanguage": "en"
                    }
                }],
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "mauriciotaranto@test.com",
                    "name": "A Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Participant A",
                    "Tabs": {
                        "TextTabs": [{
                            "TabLabel": "PreferredPhoneNumber",
                            "Value": "001234567"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "AlternatePhoneNumber",
                            "Value": "001234567"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirthMM",
                            "Value": "04"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirrthDD",
                            "Value": "18"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "BirrthYY",
                            "Value": "1981"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "DentalSchool",
                            "Value": "DentalSchool"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "MedicalSchool",
                            "Value": "MedicalSchool"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "OmsResidency",
                            "Value": "OmsResidency"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "Intership",
                            "Value": "Intership"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "Fellowship",
                            "Value": "Fellowship"
                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": " {",
                            "Value": "TrainingArea"
                        }],
                        "RadioGroupTabs": [{
                            "groupName": "RadioPhone",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "AlternatePhoneNumber",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio1"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "MemberShip",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        },
                        {
                            "groupName": "RiskManagement",
                            "radios": [{
                                "selected": true,
                                "value": "Radio2"
                            }],

                        }],
                        "checkboxTabs": [{
                            "TabLabel": "SuffixDDS",
                            "selected": true,

                        },
                        {
                            "TabLabel": "SuffixMD",
                            "selected": true,

                        },
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "2"
        }],
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4ca"
        }]
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Test flow with CC",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Amit, Thanks for your answer. Can you check my update on the question? Thanks!

Comment: As shown in my Post, the node name is `carbonCopies` not `CarbonCopy` and I have edited my answer to show how to add CC with the templates. The design pattern which you are using i.e `TemplateRole` will not provide the solution which you are expecting it to work. You need to use `CompositeTemplate` to achieve by mixing ServerTemplate and adhoc CC recipient in a single envelope.

Comment: Hi Amit just edit again my question with the correct json. Sorry I don't fully get the part of the TemplateRole does not work with that. I will need to specify the template role to send the values of my tabs. I can send both? TemplateRole  and  CompositeTemplate ??

Comment: TemplateRoles are only used when you have all the recipientRoles defined in the DS Server Template, and you do not want to add adhoc recipient which was not present in the server template. In you scenario, either CC recipient should be a CC recipienttype in your server template `07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4ca` and then you can provide the details of that recipient in the JSON while creating envelope. But if you do not want to add CC recipient in the server template, then you have to use `CompositeTemplate` to pass any adhoc recipient details in createEnvelope call.

Comment: Amit, thanks, So I understand that I need to use compositeTemplate, because I don't know the recipient. Will be dynamical. But how I set the custom fields on the compositeTemplate? using the customFields object? how do I set the RadioGroup and checkbox values? Thanks.

Comment: Amit Thanks again, does this accept also the ClientUserId property?

Comment: Yes, inside `signers` property, parallel to name and email for the signers

Comment: I will move to a new question